# Cannot read property "responseText" of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having an issue with my JSON.parse.
After I change the API call from `request` to `request.Promise.get` I receive an **error** -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseText' of undefined
```

Packages:

[Node-Schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)

[Request-Promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)

[CoinMarketCap API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest)

Is that a problem with my data in `r1` or I don't understand at all what is wrong now with the code. I was trying to change `responseText` to `responseXML` doesn't work as well for me.
Probably I'm missing the logic in the request but I'm just curious why this error appears even that this part of code was working before.

**Problem area of code**

```
const j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * * *', () => {
    requestPromise.get({
        uri: 'http://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=API-KEY-HERE',
        json: true
        resolveWithFullResponse: true
    }).then(r1 => {
        const x1 = JSON.parse(r1.target.responseText);

        const BTCdata = x1.data.find(d => d.symbol === 'BTC').quote.USD
            .volume_24h; // creating a variable to store a BTC request from API

        console.log(BTCdata);
        // Saving to database
        saveToDatabase(BTCdata);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

**Full code**

```
var requestPromise = require('request-promise');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

const saveToDatabase = function(BTCdata) {
    const url = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-1kunr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        const dbo = db.db('Crypto');
        const myobj = { Name: 'BTC', Volume: 'BTCdata' };
        dbo.collection('Crypto-Values').insertOne(myobj, (error, res) => {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log('1 document inserted');
            db.close();
        });
    });
};

function requestPromise(method, url) {
    return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
        xhr.onload = resolve;
        xhr.onerror = reject;
        xhr.send();
    }));
}

const j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * * *', () => {
    requestPromise.get({
        uri: 'http://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=API-KEY-HERE',
        json: true
        resolveWithFullResponse: true
    }).then(r1 => {
        const x1 = JSON.parse(r1.target.responseText);

        const BTCdata = x1.data.find(d => d.symbol === 'BTC').quote.USD
            .volume_24h; // creating a variable to store a BTC request from API

        console.log(BTCdata);
        // Saving to database
        saveToDatabase(BTCdata);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: I *think* `request` returns a different kind of object than `request-promise`. So there's no `target` in the second case. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request and https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise.

Comment: @BartBarnard Going to check documentations for this. Thanks for advice. Hope this helps me to solve the problem

Comment: To get a full response (rather than just respone body) you need to use "resolveWithFullResponse : true" in options. https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise#fulfilled-promises-and-the-resolvewithfullresponse-option

Comment: @6169 I made it accordingly to your advice - error stays. Updating the main question with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes here:

1. In your `requestPromise()`, your response will be already JSON since you used `json: true`, so no need to additionally `JSON.parse()` it.
2. In the very response itself (`r1` in your case), you won't have `target` key. Instead, you should probably use `r1.body` to get the body of the response first and then do with the data from the body whatever you need.

```
const j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * * *', () => {
    requestPromise.get({
        uri: 'http://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=API-KEY-HERE',
        json: true,
        resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    }).then(r1 => {
        // r1.body will contain response from API
        const responseData = r1.body;

        // do something with responseData
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

To get better idea what you will get in your `r1.body` object, refer to [official documentation](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest) or simply put that API URL with proper key in your browser and you should see JSON output already.